# What are the default Window Managers in Ubuntu and Fedora?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, window-manager

What are the default window managers in Ubuntu (11.10) and Fedora (16)? I didn't seem to be able to find it online, and if it can be installed in CrunchBang.

Comment: aw, why the downvote? :-/

Comment: I have +1 it. Because IMHO though you are expecting too much your question is genuine. I gathered some information immediately. The GNOME Shell, responsible for the new user experience in GNOME 3, runs as a plugin for Mutter. Started as a fork of Metacity. The Unity shell interface is now written in a toolkit called Nux instead of Clutter[12] and a plugin of the Compiz window manager, which Canonical states is faster than Mutter, the window manager for which GNOME Shell is a plugin.

Comment: add it as an aswer, @SachinDivekar :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default *[desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment)* on Fedora is [GNOME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME), using the [GNOME Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell).  Fedora 16 includes GNOME and GNOME Shell version 3.2.  The default desktop environment on Ubuntu is also technically GNOME, but using the [Unity shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)).  Ubuntu 11.10 also includes GNOME 3.2, but uses Unity version 4.22.0.

The default *[window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_Manager)* in Fedora w/GNOME Shell is [Mutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutter_(window_manager)).  The default window manager in Ubuntu w/Unity is [Compiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz).

GNOME 3 is not packaged for CrunchBang, but [reportedly](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/14221/gnome-3-via-debian-wheezy/) can be easily installed from the Debian testing repository.  Unity is [not currently available for Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=609278:) or CrunchBang.